# How to find out if a selected text is surrounded by an html element of not

Tags: javascript, css, textselection

I am implementing a simple text editor with content editable div and a two buttons, one for bold text and one for italic. The way I am making a text bold or italic is by inserting a `span` around the selected text with class `text-bold` and `text-italic`, respectively, and then do the styles using css. However, I don't want to keep adding `span` inside a `span` to make a text bold **and** italic like

```
<span class="text-bold">
   <span class="text-italic">Some Text</span>
</span>
```

but rather when I select a text, I want to check if it's already surrounded with a `span`, and if yes, then add a class to it to reflect the desired change. For example, suppose I already have

```
<p>Hello there
   <span class="text-bold">
      Some Text
   </span>
</p>
```

in the DOM. Later if I want to make `Some Text` in italic, I just add the class `text-italic` like so

```
<p>Hello there
   <span class="text-bold text-italic">
      Some Text
   </span>
</p>
```

I know that `selection.anchorNode.parentNode` will return the containing `p` tag, and `selection.anchorOffset` will return the offset from `p` in characters. But I am not sure how to use these data to return the surrounding `span`.

So, my question is: how can I return the surrounding html element with its attributes if exists of a selected text?

Comment: Why not just select the parent `<span class="text-bold">` elements with `.getElementsByClassName('text-bold')` then add the relevant class to all of them? Surely you don't need to do it individually?

Comment: it is a problem of tree resolution. when a sub branch becomes the whole of its parent branch then you can merge them

Comment: @ObsidianAge Because I don't know in advance if there would be a `span` with class `text-bold`. The example I gave is just an example. I expect the user to add, delete and select random text, and perform random edits. The user could decide to make a text `italic` first and then `bold`.

Comment: @MisterJojo I just want to find if a selected text is surrounded by a `span`. If yes, then add a new class. If not, then add a span around the selected text with a class that reflects the edit. Later I want to be able to toggle edits. For example, if I press `bold` button to add `span` with `text-bold` class. If I press it again, then I remove the class, and ultimately remove any `span` that contains no classes.

Comment: yes, but you will still need to browse your part of the tree to know the configuration of the nodes concerned

Comment: @MisterJojo OK, do you have pointers how to start on this?

Comment: what? some links on the mdn doc? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: That's not really what you'll want. ex. `<span class='bold'>` **This is not what you want** `</span>`, Then later on you want to italicize the word *`want`*. Now your function detects `.bold` and you get `<span class='bold italics'>` ***This is not what you want*** `</span>`. The word ***`want`*** is italicized *but* so is the rest of the `<span>` . If you are using `selection` and `range` API then you need to be precise and have complete control of your phrasing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.nodeName
```

Comment: make sure to explain your proposed solution so its clear what your code actually does